# Does Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 include Gnome 3.2.2?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I just now downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1, and I'm wondering if that download includes Gnome 3.2.2 or if I'll have to download Gnome separately and incorporate later.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean 3.20.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. download and install [Ubuntu GNOME](//ubuntugnome.org/) which is shipped with the GNOME desktop environment (and without Unity) or
2. after installing Ubuntu, [install the GNOME desktop environment](/q/614657/175814) from the package repositories.